# deploy.rb: undefined local variable or method `home` for main:Object

Tags: ruby, capistrano3

I know there are a lot of questions regarding this error message, but I couldn't find one where this error is happening in the same context as mine.

I'm trying to migrate a previously working Capistrano configuration from version 2 to Capistrano 3. Unfortunately, calling `cap production deploy --dry-run` generates the error

```
cap aborted!
undefined local variable or method `home' for main:Object
/myapp/config/deploy.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
```

Here's the content of `deploy.rb` up to line 6 where the error occurs:

```ruby
set :user, "myuser"
set :application, "myapp"
set :domain, "mydomain"
set :repository, "git@github.com:acme/myapp.git"
set :home, "/home/myuser"
set :deploy_to, "#{home}/#{domain}"
```

I don't know much about Ruby, but from what I've gathered, the colon means these are symbols, not variables, and in the [Capistrano documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/preparing-your-application/) they're using the same syntax to define "variables" (see paragraph 5 "Set the shared information in deploy.rb")?

The deploy script ran flawlessly on OS X with Ruby 2.0.0p247 and Capistrano 2.9.0. Now on CentOS with Ruby 1.9.3p545 and Capistrano 3.1.0, the error mentioned above occurs. I've made several changes to the `Capfile` to get it running with Capistrano 3, but left the `deploy.rb` untouched, hoping it would work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think Capistrano will create local variables for you, but you can do so yourself:

```
domain = "mydomain"
home = "/home/myuser"

set :domain, domain
set :home, home
set :deploy_to, "#{home}/#{domain}"
```

Alternatively, you can use [`fetch`](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/07ed19178e6a16b6d80f1a7da584051097078904/lib/capistrano/dsl/env.rb#L9-L11), the counterpart to `set`:

```
set :domain, "mydomain"
set :home, "/home/myuser"
set :deploy_to, "#{fetch(:home)}/#{fetch(:domain)}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer. I can't understand how most examples omit that variable definition. This one, for instance https://gist.github.com/matthewcopeland/3803403